# node-redで計算を行いたいですが、コードの記述方法がわからない

Tags: javascript

node-redで以下の計算を行いたいのですが、functionに何と書き込めばいいのでしょうか？

```
=217*(6.1078*10^(7.5*T/(T+237.3)))/(T+273.15)
```

なおＴが前のノードで取得してきた数値とご認識ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

手元で試せていないのですが、おそらく以下で動くのではないかと思います。

```
input = Number(msg.payload);
msg.payload = 217 * (6.1078 * Math.pow(10, 7.5 * input / (input + 237.3))) / (input + 273.15);
return msg;
```

参考: https://nodered.jp/docs/user-guide/writing-functions